Power Apps form with modern Table is not displaying values of multiselect choice fields
I added a modern table control to a Power App form. The table is connected to a SharePoint Online list, which only has some test data rows so far. The multi select choice fields which allow multiple values (and contain data with multiple values) are showing completely blank. Choice fields that allow single values are showing values.
All the data cards showing the fields under the Table in tree view have a question mark to the left of them. The fields have limited properties compared to fields that show in edit form. Something to do with the "modern"ness of the table control, I'm assuming. I only need this table to for viewing data and selecting records to open a separate edit form.

(An edit form opens when a record is selected in this table. That form is showing "INJECT0" error and four digits integers for the person system fields of 'created by' and 'modified by' but that I probably need to ask separately. Mentioning here in case helps diagnose. The data in that form is coming from this table. These system fields show correctly in the table though.)

It looks like modifying and formatting modern Table columns' data is not yet supported, based on MS Article here
However, I think, we can create a new data collection based on the source data (SharePoint List), and concatenate multi-value choices into a comma separated text. If you investigate the source, multi-value choices are returned as [Table] column that can be fed to Concat() function.
Then the Source of the Modern Table control can be set to the new Collection.
This Fx can be added to the On-Start of the application.
Here is an example that I've tested with

//Clear the collection 
  ClearCollect(varTempContact, Blank());

     ForAll(
    'Test Contact',
     Collect(
        varTempContact,
        {
            FirstName: ThisRecord.FirstName,
            LastName: ThisRecord.LastName,
            OriginalFruits:ThisRecord.FavoriteFruits,
            NewFruits: Concat(ThisRecord.FavoriteFruits, Value, ", ")               
            
        }
    )
)



For this example, the Modern Table Control's Items property was set to varTempContact


Thank you! Worked. Also solved my people column issue which was also showing blank. Adding a '.DisplayName' after that field (in the collection object) populated the name as field value for my table. (Tried making a collection as data source for my table yesterday per some advice, but the collection wasn't showing as a data source option, even though the object existed with its columns. Maybe needed to sleep on it or I hadn't refreshed browser.)
